# redirectToPostedUrl with object (Model) passed to it and keep template resolving

Tags: plugin-development, routes

I am creating a plugin where the user is submitting data to a controller.

With a successful saving of the data in the controller/service I want to honour the standardised redirect param:

`<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="success/{stripeId}"/>`

The stripeId is a property of the PaymentModel $payment being passed to the redirectToPostedUrl param:

`$this->redirectToPostedUrl($payment);`

This works in that when the person is redirected the person is brought to page desired with url like this:

`http://web.dev/success/ch_5GW2RFTNvW8qeR`

The problem is that craft cannot find the success template and the success page does not show since it is trying to find a template a `success/` directory called `ch_5GW2RFTNvW8qeR.html`

2 Solutions I have found:

**Option 1)** My plugin users need to set up a route manually in the control panel to allow this to resolve correctly (and have full control over where the success page is and what the url looks like):

[image: image of manual route setup]

**Option 2)** The other option is that I use the Plugin hook `registerSiteRoutes` to register a front end route to that template. The obvious problem with that is I either need to make that hard coded, or user configurable (pain).

Since I would obviously need to make it user configurable, it kinda defeats the purpose of the user of the plugin being able to decide the `name="redirect" value="success/{stripeId}"` in the first place. I would imagine I would have to come up with my own redirection/routing config and logic. I understand this is not a problem in the control panel actions since I know what I want my urls to be, but as a plugin developer I want to give flexibility to users of my plugin to choose their front-end urls.

Any thoughts? I am leaning towards having to put into the documentation of my plugin that they need to do option 1 above, but still think its not optimal.

Edit: 
Just had another idea. **Option 3)** Since I will be giving my users demo templates for the front end forms on installation - should I possibly create a route in the `craft_routes` table for  the user? That way on first install everything should work without needing to manually set up a bunch of routes manually to match my demo templates.

Comment: Couldn't you also just redirect to `http://web.dev/success?id=ch_5GW2RFTNvW8qeR`

Comment: yes indeed Brad, will consider that the best option so far. Not as aesthetically pleasing but works!!! You the man, have a drink of water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the prettiest URL, but I think the simplest solution would be to redirect to something like:

```
http://web.dev/success?id=ch_5GW2RFTNvW8qeR
```